# Facebook Share not scraping image on first try, but on second try after caching happens

Tags: facebook, image, button, share

I have implemented a SHARE button that uses the sharer.php method. The image does not get **scraped** on the first try, but only after the second try. I assume after it has been cached by Facebook servers.

Here's my URL and what happens when I click on the SHARE button

http://viddsee.com/video.php?video=wild_fire_2011

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fviddsee.com%2Fvideo.php%3Fvideo%3Dwild_fire_2011

Any help will be appreciated!

Derek

Answer (score 4):

It's a pre-cache issue. Check here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#pre-cache-images

Comment: That's correct. The above hack seems to resolve the issue by pre-caching the URL prior to hitting the share button

Comment: Holy heck. Adding the og:image:width/height tags saved my bacon, this is glorious. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I found a not-so-elegant workaround to this problem. I found out that this didn't happens when i used the facebook **scraper** (debugger) before trying to share a new link, so i started searching for a way to do this before a user shares the link.

This is my solution, which works about 80% of the time (jQuery):

```
$.post("https://graph.facebook.com/?id="+encodeURIComponent(url_to_be_shared)+"&scrape=true",
    function(contents){
        //here you do the facebook share code
    });
```

This sometimes fails with no response at all, so you might want to add something like this:

```
$.post("https://graph.facebook.com/?id="+encodeURIComponent(url_to_be_shared)+"&scrape=true",
    function(contents){
        //here you do the facebook share code
    }).fail(function(){
        //call function again if failed
    });
```

Like i said, this is a not-elegant solution, and it works around the 80% of the time, to maximize this i did an even less elegant solution and nested three (yea, three) post calls to the facebook graph api, it takes about 2 - 5 seconds to complete the three calls, but it's something. After doing this i thought maybe i could check for the ajax.post response to check if it changes when it doesn't find the image, so i could iterate over that, but i haven't found the time to do that, so if you end up checking that up, let me know.

Regards

Comment: Cool hack. I tried several ways of implementing the share button (FB SDK HTML5 & Iframe / Telerik) and could not avoid the pre-caching issue. This hack definitely seems to do the trick. Thanks